# Opened ports in OS and Router but still outside websites can't see it open

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have set my computer to be in DMZ, router firewall is off and also Windows firewall is allowing the port (UDP 27015) to go through but when I check it with websites like

- http://canyouseeme.org/
- https://portchecker.co/check

they all report that the port is closed!

I used this piece of software

http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/portlistener/download.shtml

to make UDP 27015 a listening port.

I just talked to my ISP and they said they haven't closed any ports on my network. so I'm really clueless now. what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have a service currently listening on port 27015?

Comment: @n8te yes Steam's VOIP

Comment: DON'T open all the doors to your computer. For port forwarding you don't need any software but that of your router.